# Can't play YouTube videos with libVLC, media.subItems() is empty (Android, Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, parsing, lua, youtube, libvlc

I've been trying to play youtube videos with libVLC on android with no success.
Direct URLs work fine, but when I'm parsing the media item with a YouTube URI, media.subItems() is empty and I get an *IndexOutOfBoundsException* when I try to set mediaPlayer.media to the first subItem.

There isn't much about this matter anywhere, so I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if it's not possible for libVLC to extract the direct URL of the YouTube video?

**This is my code**

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_room)

        libVLC = LibVLC(this, ArrayList<String>().apply {
            add("--no-drop-late-frames")
            add("--no-skip-frames")
            add("--rtsp-tcp")
            add("-vvv")
        })
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer(libVLC)
        videoLayout = findViewById(R.id.vlcVideoLayout)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        mediaPlayer?.attachViews(videoLayout!!, null, ENABLE_SUBTITLES, USE_TEXTURE_VIEW)

        binding.vlcPlayPauseBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if (mediaPlayer?.isPlaying == true) pauseMedia()
            else playMedia()
        }

        try {
//            setPlayerMedia("https://storage.googleapis.com/our-cursor-321600/4HXA6RHZI19/23aasc22_1628465085.22.0_71605.mp4")
            setPlayerMediaYt("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIys-oLYq6s")

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }


    }

    private fun setPlayerMedia(url: String) {
        val uri = Uri.parse(url)

        Media(libVLC, uri).apply {
            setHWDecoderEnabled(true, false)
            addOption(":network-caching=150")
            addOption(":clock-jitter=0")
            addOption(":clock-synchro=0")
            mediaPlayer?.media = this
        }.release()

        mediaPlayer?.play()
    }

    private fun setPlayerMediaYt(url: String) {
        val uri = Uri.parse(url)
        val media = Media(libVLC, uri)
        media.setEventListener { event ->
            when (event.type) {
                ParsedChanged -> {
                    if (media.isParsed) {
                        mediaPlayer?.media = media.subItems().getMediaAt(0)
                        media.release()
                        mediaPlayer?.play()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        media.parseAsync(IMedia.Parse.ParseNetwork)
    }
}
```

**This is the log**

```
2021-08-09 10:00:53.380 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ad9a10/6e697274535f676e] libvlc libvlc: VLC media player - 3.0.16 Vetinari
2021-08-09 10:00:53.380 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ad9a10/38762d34366d7261] libvlc libvlc: Copyright © 1996-2021 the VideoLAN team
2021-08-09 10:00:53.380 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ad9a10/2235] libvlc libvlc: revision 3.0.16-72-g6132eb5a85
2021-08-09 10:00:53.380 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ad9a10/2245] libvlc libvlc: configured with ../configure  '--host=aarch64-linux-android' '--build=x86_64-unknown-linux' '--with-contrib=/builds/videolan/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/aarch64-linux-android' '--prefix=/builds/videolan/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-aarch64-linux-android/install/' '--with-pic' '--disable-nls' '--enable-live555' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-avformat' '--enable-swscale' '--enable-avcodec' '--enable-opus' '--enable-opensles' '--enable-matroska' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-dvbpsi' '--disable-vlc' '--disable-shared' '--disable-update-check' '--disable-vlm' '--disable-dbus' '--enable-lua' '--disable-vcd' '--disable-v4l2' '--enable-dvdread' '--enable-dvdnav' '--enable-bluray' '--disable-linsys' '--disable-decklink' '--disable-libva' '--disable-dv1394' '--enable-mod' '--disable-sid' '--disable-gme' '--disable-tremor' '--disable-mad' '--enable-mpg123' '--disable-dca' '--disable-sdl-image' '--enable-zvbi' '--disable-fluidsynth' '--enable-fluidlite' '--disable-jack' '--disable-pulse'
2021-08-09 10:00:53.380 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ad9a10/7abe099d30] libvlc libvlc: plug-ins loaded: 367 modules
2021-08-09 10:00:53.380 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ada410/0] libvlc logger: looking for logger module matching "any": 4 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:53.380 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ada410/0] libvlc logger: using logger module "android_logger"
2021-08-09 10:00:53.380 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ad9a10/6fed] libvlc libvlc: translation test: code is "C"
2021-08-09 10:00:53.380 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9550/6fed] libvlc keystore: looking for keystore module matching "memory": 3 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:53.380 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9550/6fed] libvlc keystore: using keystore module "memory"
2021-08-09 10:00:53.380 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ad9a10/6fed] libvlc libvlc: CPU has capabilities FPU 
2021-08-09 10:00:53.382 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007b60584d10/6fed] libvlc generic: creating audio output
2021-08-09 10:00:53.382 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007abdfd6590/6fed] libvlc audio output: looking for audio output module matching "android_audiotrack": 4 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:53.384 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007abdfd6590/6fed] libvlc audio output: using audio output module "android_audiotrack"
2021-08-09 10:00:53.384 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007b60584d10/6fed] libvlc generic: keeping audio output
2021-08-09 10:00:53.396 28653-28780/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace6da490/706c] libvlc input: Creating an input for preparsing 'watch?v=CIys-oLYq6s'
2021-08-09 10:00:53.397 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace6da490/706d] libvlc input: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
2021-08-09 10:00:53.397 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace6da490/706d] libvlc input: using default timeshift path
2021-08-09 10:00:53.397 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace6da490/706d] libvlc input: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIys-oLYq6s' gives access `https' demux `any' path `www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIys-oLYq6s'
2021-08-09 10:00:53.397 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9adab90/706d] libvlc demux: looking for access_demux module matching "https": 7 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:53.397 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9adab90/706d] libvlc demux: no access_demux modules matched
2021-08-09 10:00:53.397 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007b60516f10/706d] libvlc stream: creating access: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIys-oLYq6s
2021-08-09 10:00:53.397 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007b60516f10/706d] libvlc stream: looking for access module matching "https": 25 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:53.397 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9b70/706d] libvlc tls client: looking for tls client module matching "any": 1 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:53.397 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9b70/706d] libvlc tls client: using GnuTLS version 3.6.15
2021-08-09 10:00:53.421 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9b70/706d] libvlc tls client: loaded 138 trusted CAs from system
2021-08-09 10:00:53.422 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9b70/706d] libvlc tls client: using tls client module "gnutls"
2021-08-09 10:00:53.422 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9b70/706d] libvlc tls client: resolving www.youtube.com ...
2021-08-09 10:00:53.477 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9b70/706d] libvlc tls client: TLS handshake: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
2021-08-09 10:00:54.582 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9b70/706d] libvlc tls client: TLS handshake: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
2021-08-09 10:00:54.584 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9b70/706d] libvlc tls client: TLS handshake: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
2021-08-09 10:00:54.586 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9b70/706d] libvlc tls client: TLS handshake: Success.
2021-08-09 10:00:54.673 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007b60516f10/706d] libvlc stream: using access module "access"
2021-08-09 10:00:54.673 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9a85210/706d] libvlc stream: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_block": 26 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:54.673 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9a85210/706d] libvlc stream: using 16777216 bytes buffer, 16777216 bytes read
2021-08-09 10:00:54.673 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9a85210/706d] libvlc stream: using stream_filter module "prefetch"
2021-08-09 10:00:54.673 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007a5ab05f10/706d] libvlc stream: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 26 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:54.677 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007a5ab05f10/706d] libvlc stream: Trying Lua scripts in /data/user/0/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty/app_vlc/.share/lua/playlist
2021-08-09 10:00:54.677 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007a5ab05f10/706d] libvlc stream: Trying Lua scripts in /data/app/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty-MqKCoX9olwtJ2W9NHMiEhw==/vlc/lua/playlist
2021-08-09 10:00:54.677 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007a5ab05f10/706d] libvlc stream: Trying Lua scripts in /system/usr/share/lua/playlist
2021-08-09 10:00:54.677 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007a5ab05f10/706d] libvlc stream: no stream_filter modules matched
2021-08-09 10:00:54.677 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007abe1c6a50/706d] libvlc stream_directory: looking for stream_directory module matching "any": 1 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:54.677 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007abe1c6a50/706d] libvlc stream_directory: no stream_directory modules matched
2021-08-09 10:00:54.677 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9adaa50/706d] libvlc input source: attachment of directory-extractor failed for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIys-oLYq6s
2021-08-09 10:00:54.677 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007a5ab05f10/706d] libvlc stream: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 26 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:54.677 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007a5ab05f10/706d] libvlc stream: using stream_filter module "record"
2021-08-09 10:00:54.677 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007abe1c6a50/706d] libvlc demux: looking for demux module matching "any": 49 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:54.699 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007a5aaf9090/706d] libvlc xml reader: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:54.699 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007a5aaf9090/706d] libvlc xml reader: using xml reader module "xml"
2021-08-09 10:00:54.699 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007abe1c6a50/706d] libvlc demux: subtitle demux discarded
2021-08-09 10:00:54.699 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007abe1c6a50/706d] libvlc demux: MOD validation failed (ext=)
2021-08-09 10:00:54.699 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007abe1c6a50/706d] libvlc demux: TS module discarded (lost sync)
2021-08-09 10:00:54.699 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007abe1c6a50/706d] libvlc demux: trying url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIys-oLYq6s
2021-08-09 10:00:54.699 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007abe1c6a50/706d] libvlc demux: CPU flags: 0x00000068
2021-08-09 10:00:54.699 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007abe1c6a50/706d] libvlc demux: couldn't guess format
2021-08-09 10:00:54.699 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty W/VLC: [0000007abe1c6a50/706d] libvlc demux: this does not look like an MPEG PS stream, continuing anyway
2021-08-09 10:00:54.700 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007abe1c6a50/706d] libvlc demux: using demux module "ps"
2021-08-09 10:00:54.700 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9a90/706d] libvlc demux meta: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:54.700 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9a90/706d] libvlc demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /data/user/0/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty/app_vlc/.share/lua/meta/reader
2021-08-09 10:00:54.700 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9a90/706d] libvlc demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /data/app/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty-MqKCoX9olwtJ2W9NHMiEhw==/vlc/lua/meta/reader
2021-08-09 10:00:54.700 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9a90/706d] libvlc demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /system/usr/share/lua/meta/reader
2021-08-09 10:00:54.700 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9ae9a90/706d] libvlc demux meta: no meta reader modules matched
2021-08-09 10:00:54.700 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace6da490/706d] libvlc input: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIys-oLYq6s' successfully opened
2021-08-09 10:00:54.700 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007abe1c6a50/706d] libvlc demux: removing module "ps"
2021-08-09 10:00:54.700 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007a5ab05f10/706d] libvlc stream: removing module "record"
2021-08-09 10:00:54.700 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9a85210/706d] libvlc stream: removing module "prefetch"
2021-08-09 10:00:54.700 28653-28815/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ac9a85210/708f] libvlc stream: end of stream
2021-08-09 10:00:54.700 28653-28781/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007b60516f10/706d] libvlc stream: removing module "access"
2021-08-09 10:00:54.703 28653-28817/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace69c410/7091] libvlc meta fetcher: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:54.703 28653-28817/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace69c410/7091] libvlc meta fetcher: Trying Lua scripts in /data/user/0/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty/app_vlc/.share/lua/meta/fetcher
2021-08-09 10:00:54.703 28653-28817/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace69c410/7091] libvlc meta fetcher: Trying Lua scripts in /data/app/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty-MqKCoX9olwtJ2W9NHMiEhw==/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
2021-08-09 10:00:54.703 28653-28817/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace69c410/7091] libvlc meta fetcher: Trying Lua scripts in /system/usr/share/lua/meta/fetcher
2021-08-09 10:00:54.703 28653-28817/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace69c410/7091] libvlc meta fetcher: no meta fetcher modules matched
2021-08-09 10:00:54.703 28653-28817/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace69c410/7091] libvlc art finder: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
2021-08-09 10:00:54.703 28653-28817/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace69c410/7091] libvlc art finder: Trying Lua scripts in /data/user/0/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty/app_vlc/.share/lua/meta/art
2021-08-09 10:00:54.703 28653-28817/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace69c410/7091] libvlc art finder: Trying Lua scripts in /data/app/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty-MqKCoX9olwtJ2W9NHMiEhw==/vlc/lua/meta/art
2021-08-09 10:00:54.703 28653-28817/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace69c410/7091] libvlc art finder: Trying Lua scripts in /system/usr/share/lua/meta/art
2021-08-09 10:00:54.703 28653-28817/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty D/VLC: [0000007ace69c410/7091] libvlc art finder: no art finder modules matched
2021-08-09 10:00:54.705 28653-28653/xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty, PID: 28653
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at org.videolan.libvlc.MediaList.getMediaAt(MediaList.java:147)
        at xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty.room.RoomActivity.setPlayerMediaYt$lambda-3(RoomActivity.kt:110)
        at xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty.room.RoomActivity.lambda$FZqfUiLSiuCcVV6htyvPRvUZUKs(Unknown Source:0)
        at xyz.pbyte.mywatchparty.room.-$$Lambda$RoomActivity$FZqfUiLSiuCcVV6htyvPRvUZUKs.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
        at org.videolan.libvlc.VLCObject$1EventRunnable.run(VLCObject.java:172)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7551)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: if the vlc app can play it, then maybe your libvlc version is out of date and youtube parsing fails

Comment: @mfkl This is the version I'm using: implementation 'org.videolan.android:libvlc-all:3.4.0-eap8'

Comment: @mfkl As far as could find, the one I'm using should be the latest stable version. I Also tried with previous versions, but still the same result. Do you have any other guesses as to why this might be happening? Thank you!

Comment: calling back into libvlc from its callback is usually discouraged, might be the issue here though

Comment: @mfkl I also tried doing it like this, but with no success `val uri = Uri.parse(url)
        val media = Media(libVLC, uri)
        media.parse(IMedia.Parse.ParseNetwork)
        mediaPlayer?.media = media.subItems().getMediaAt(0)
        media.release()
        mediaPlayer?.play()` Also, I think I made an error in the title. The subItems MediaList is empty not null, hence the _IndexOutOfBoundsException_.

Comment: maybe try this `media.addOption(":no-http-forward-cookies")` before you call parse

Comment: @mfkl I added `media.addOption(":no-http-forward-cookies")` but nothing changed. [Here](https://pastebin.com/gKQHnG4g) is the complete log if you want to take a look since the one above is filtered with "libvlc"

Comment: remove `add("--rtsp-tcp")` (though I doubt that will fix it, it's just incorrect though)

Comment: @mfkl Removed it, still the same. I'm lost in this :d

Comment: Start from the VLC Android code is your best bet

Comment: does `parseAsync` return true?

Comment: @mfkl both parse and parseAsync return true